# Maven slow execution time with different versions

Tags: java, maven, build

I have a project builded with Maven. Usually, we used 3.2.5 version, but in last time we tried to do a minor upgrade. 
Builds with integration tests for different Maven versions:
3.2.5 - 11 min
3.3.0 - 11 min
3.3.9 - 13 min
3.5.0 - 24 min
3.5.4 - 1h
3.6.3 - 1h

Do you have any idea, what can be a problem here? 
I saw that when we rised version to 3.5.0 which has colouring for logs, it improved execution time a lot, especially logs that are arriving on console are much slower.

That's the command line I use to execute maven:
`mvn -Dstyle.color=never -T 1C -am clean install -Pbuild-all,integration`

Comment: So which parts of the build take most of the time?

Comment: If you are running tests you should check the test for their runtime ...apart from that using `-T 1C` does not speed up your tests...furthermore an integration test is usually by definition not parallelizable...You should use the most recent version of Maven and really check your tests ....

Comment: Integration tests. They print a lot to console and it's really slower on versions up from 3.5.0.

Comment: Could you check what happens if you stop writing so much on the console?

Comment: Set every logging thing to FATAL and execution time on Maven 3.5.4 lasts 9 minutes. However, on older Maven versions it worked normally, even with writing almost everything on console.

Comment: You should check to use `--batch-mode` apart from that I would strongly recommend to prevent output on console for integration tests ....

Comment: Using --batch-mode doesn't help.

Comment: BTW: Are you running on plain command line or on a ci solution like Jenkins?

Comment: Have you checked your build with `-DskipTests` how long it takes?

Comment: One other check you could run your build via `mvn clean verify ... >x.log 2>&1` to redirect all output to a file ....

Comment: @khmarbaise, for redirecting all output to file it works fine (15 minutes).  Skipping tests also lasts in a while (7 minutes).

Comment: So the tests are the real problem...7 Minutes for a build..how many modules/classes/lines of code do you have? Cause 7 minutes is a long time? That means in consequence that your tests taking 8 minutes to run? I would strongly recommend to check the tests what they are doing etc. How many unit tests do you have? How many integration tests do you have?

Comment: Somthing like 10k of tests. It's a real big project.

However, if I execute it with tests but redirect output to file it's working fine. Same for Maven < 3.3.9. So I think there's a problem with communication between Maven 3.5+ and Console. Maven 3.3.3 and 3.2.5 is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Real big is relative I had projects with 30k tests (2.8 million lines of code) about 5 k integration tests (800+ maven modules). It's very important that a test should never log/write to console (this will keep the logs on CI clean and easily to read) ..and yes with Maven 3.5+ the color support has been added which I think is the reason. But that means that your tests are heavily using the console during tests ...furthermore you should cleanly separate between unit and integration tests...

Comment: Yup, I agree that's relative. So if there's a problem with color support I think that's here nothing to do. The only solution probably is to just set off logging (to the console). Thanks.